# Properly update textColor and Drawable in customised Layout in selected/pressed ListView items

Tags: android, listview, selector

I have a customised Layout for a ListView, hosted in a Navigation Drawer. Here's the Layout for the adapter:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:src="@drawable/nav_drawer_icon_states" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@drawable/nav_drawer_text_states" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my `/res/drawable` folder I have the `nav_drawer_text_states.xml` as:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:state_window_focused="true" android:color="@color/white"/>
    <item android:color="@color/gray"/>
</selector>
```

and have tested with simple selector as this too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

The pressed and default color works, but the intermediate state, when I have selected an item the ListView:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

with the code:

```
mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
```

doesn't change the selected text to white.

Any help is appreciated.

---

### UPDATED

I changed the `nav_drawer_text_states.xml` to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/pink"/>
    <item android:state_activated="true" android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:color="@color/second_row_playlists"/>

</selector>
```

and it worked, BUT the state_activated="true" is API11+ and my app is API8+.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**< rant >** Unfortunately Android is really bad in pre-Honeycomb versions, and the market don't want to let these versions die. **< / rant >**

I solved by doing by hand everything in an Adapter. If anyone still cares, here's the solution:

```
public class NavigationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int mSelectedPosition;

    public NavigationAdapter(Context context, String[] items) {
        super(context, R.layout.cell_navigation_drawer, items);
        this.mSelectedPosition = 0;
    }

    public void setItemChecked(int position) {
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            ...
        }

        ...

        Resources res = getContext().getResources();
        if (position == mSelectedPosition) {
            textView.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.white));
        } else {
            textView.setTextColor(res.getColor(R.color.gray));
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and changed the method when clicked to:

```
public void setItemChecked(int position, boolean value) {
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    mMyAdapter.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}
```